# Odd behavior from UITabBar where background color only shows for one tab

Tags: ios, swift3, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I am using `Swift 3` and I researched various methods to set the `backgroundColor` color of a `UITabBar`. The most simple method was to change the property in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` of the `AppDelegate`. When I tried to do this, the `UITabBar` launches with the standard color, which is not my intended result.

However, when I go to the next tab, the `UITabBar` color gets changed to my  intended color.

Following this, I tried to `subclass` my `UITabBarController` and I tried to set the background colors in both the `viewDidLoad` and in the `viewDidLayoutSubViews`. All three of these attempts exhibited the exact same behavior - which was the `UITabBar` launched with the standard color, and only changed colors when I tabbed to the next tab.

Here is my code:

#### App Delegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) 
    -> Bool {
        UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        return true
}
```

#### viewDidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tabBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
}
```

#### viewDidLayoutSubviews

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    self.tabBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
}
```

My questions are the following:

1) Can I eliminate this as being a constraint issue? I didn't modify or set any constraints for the `UITabBar`

2) I have a launch screen where the user selects acknowledges something and then they are `segued` to the `UITabBarController`. Could this be part of the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic way to change to a tab bar's color is not to set its `backgroundColor` as you are doing, but rather to set its `barTintColor`. (For more sophisticated control, use a colored `backgroundImage`.)

Comment: Yes, this is a good method, however why are these two colors appearing differently when I use `UIColor.red` in the `UITabBar` compared to the `UINavigationBar` ? Can I make them the same?
`UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.red`
`UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.red`

Comment: I told you. If you want exact control over the color, use the `backgroundImage`. Also watch out for the translucency.

Comment: Also you are doing the navigation bar color wrong too. Two wrongs do not make a right. Set the bar tint color, never the background color.

Comment: Thank you for identifying I incorrectly used `backgroundColor` to set the `UINavigationBar` & `UITabBar`. Switching to a consistent color in both the `UINavigationBar` and in the UITabBar` was my intended result and using the `barTintColor` for both items solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Putting this in my app delegate gets me a tab bar that's tinted red.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let tabBarVC = UITabBarController()
    tabBarVC.viewControllers = [FirstViewController(), SecondViewController()]
    tabBarVC.tabBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    window?.rootViewController = tabBarVC
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dan! Is there a way to do this without having to specify the type and number of `viewControllers`?

Comment: Sure, that part of the code was just an example. You can configure the tab bar's color wherever you initialize the `UITabBarController`. Although as mentioned above, `barTintColor` is the appropriate property to set.