# xcode8 . storyboard background color not changing

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

Created a new project  in xcode8 and added a navigation bar in story board.  set the background to black its displaying light black color.  Tried with different color but still displays a lighter version.  How do i fix this.  Tried with different settings but still not changing.  Attached a screen shot.
[image]

Comment: Don't change the background color of a navigation bar. Change the _bar tint_ color (shown much higher up in your screen shot, right at the top, just under Style). See also my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41053555/341994

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, "Lead" is not the darkest shade, the one to the left of it is.

Second of all, do you have night shift turned on for your device? It changes the look of colours since it adds a tint to your screen. You can check this by swiping up from the bottom of your phone to access control center.

Lastly, make sure you're changing the background colour of the actual view and not the navigation bar.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Was changing the background setting instead of bartint colour it works now

Comment: Glad it helped! Please mark my answer as correct since it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the part under the Navigation Controller, you can uncheck `Translucent`.

If you mean the entire background, you may need to choose `View` from the LFH hierarchy, then find `Alpha` in the RHS under `Attribute Inspector`.

If nothing changed, change that in programmatically by adding this to your viewDidLoad() `view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: /*some Value*/, green: /*some Value*/, blue: /*some Value*/, alpha: /*some Value*/)`